# Is it possible to configure Biblatex to only show URL of an entry if it has no DOI?

Tags: biblatex, urls

Can I configure Biblatex so that the URL, for entries that have both a `url` and a `doi` field, is normally not shown in the bibliography. The URL is only shown for entries that have no `doi` field.

Answer (score 3):

One could redefine the `url` bibmacro to test whether the `doi` field is defined.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foo
  ,author={bar}
  ,title={baz}
  ,year={2018}
  ,URL={foo.com}
  ,DOI={135.123.5}
}

@article{foo2
  ,author={bar2}
  ,title={baz2}
  ,year={20182}
  ,URL={foo.com2}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\letbibmacro{urlBAK}{url}
\renewbibmacro{url}{\iffieldundef{doi}{\usebibmacro{urlBAK}}{}}

\begin{document}
\cite{foo}
\cite{foo2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]